# I do not understand something about Java Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

It Does Not Work, and i don't know why... I'm new in java world.

```
public class Mixed2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A c = new C();
        c.m1();
        c.m2();
        c.m3("My text");
    }
}
class A {
    void m1() {
        System.out.print("A's m1, ");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    void m2() {
        System.out.print("B's m2, ");
    }
}
class C extends B {
    void m3(Object text) {
        System.out.print("C's m3, " + text);
    }
}
```

---

```
Mixed2.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        c.m2();
         ^
  symbol:   method m2()
  location: variable c of type A
Mixed2.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        c.m3("My text");
         ^
  symbol:   method m3(String)
  location: variable c of type A
2 errors
```

is because A don't have m2 and m3 methods?If i put in A m2 and m3 it works, but B m2 and C m3 are called. I do not understand.

Comment: Your reference is to an `A`. So even though the runtime type is a `C` the compiler has no way of knowing that. You can only access methods defined on an `A` from a reference to an `A`.

Answer (score 4):

1. There's no use of polymorphism in your code.
2. Your variable is an `A` variable, and thus the m2 and m3 methods do not exist for this type, and can't be used without casting, which defeats the purpose of OOP.

I would rename method `m2()` in B to `m1()`, and then you'll get true polymorphism:

```
class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void m1() {
        // do you want to call the super's method here?
        // if so, then call
        // super.m1();

        System.out.print("B's m1, ");
    }
}
```

Class c's m3 method requires a parameter, and so polymorphism won't work for it as its signature cannot match that of m1's.

---

**Edit**
You ask in comment:

> sorry is about Inheritance and . i dont know ... is a reference of type A who keep an object of type C ... then c should have idea about the m3?

Your c variable is an A type variable that references a C object. Only A methods will be available to that variable unless you explicitly cast it to something else:

```
((C)c).m3("foo");
```

Which is brittle and ugly code. If you want to demonstrate polymorphism, then your child class method should override a parent method.

Comment: sorry is about Inheritance and . i dont know ... is a reference of type A who keep an object of type C ... then c should have idea about the m3?

Answer (score 1):

Although you constructed an object of type `C`, the reference to the object is of type `A`.
You can do this because `C` is a subclass of `A`, but you can only access methods that are declared in `A`.